# Is Delete cascade possible in ravendb

Tags: c#, ravendb

Still just a starter in ravendb. I have a doubt whether raven db supports some kind of referential integrity.

Here is my doubt and work..

I have document type screens as below

```
public class Screens 
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String ScreenName { get; set; }
}
```

And Another document named RightsDeclaration as below

```
public class RightsDeclaration 
    {
        public RightsDeclaration()
        {
            _screenrights = new List<ScreenRight>();
        }

        public String Id { get; set; }// Role Name 
        List<ScreenRight> _screenrights;
        public List<ScreenRight> ScreenRights { get { return _screenrights; } set { _screenrights = value; } }
}
```

Now the screen rights class looks like below with the screen name field as below

```
public class ScreenRight :
    {

        public String ScreenName { get; set; }
        public Boolean Create { get; set; }
        public Boolean Read { get; set; }
        public Boolean Update { get; set; }
        public Boolean Delete { get; set; }
        public Boolean Approve { get; set; }
        public Boolean Access { get; set; }
        public Boolean Print { get; set; }
        public Boolean Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now first i will create some list of screens and then i assign rights for each role
with mentioning what is the screen name and list of rights. up to this point everything goes fine. Now in a scenario where if i would delete the screen name in screens class but then the screen rights for that screen still exists in the rights declaration. is it possible to delete the corresponding screen rights  from userrights document too?
if so please mention the query or idea to do the above..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raven doesn't support true referential integrity, that's not something document databases are typically interested in.  You can, however, achieve the same effect.

First, I wouldn't reference via name, the screen Id is a better key because you can load by it.  If you want to also capture the screen name in your `ScreenRight` class, that's fine but it's a secondary concern.

Also, a minor thing, but try to keep your entity/document names singular.  `Screen` instead of `Screens`.  It will save you some trouble down the road.

One way to handle the delete would be to specifically update the referencing document when you delete the primary.  If you do this in the same session, you have transactional guarantees.  You do have to consider paging of query results.

```cs
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var screen = session.Load<Screen>(screenId);
    if (screen != null)
    {
        // Set up some variables to help with pagination.
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        const int pageSize = 1024;
        var page = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            // Get all rights that use this screen.
            // Waiting for nonstale results is appropriate, but we want the same "now" with each page.
            var rights = session.Query<RightsDeclaration>()
                                .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOf(now))
                                .Where(x => x.ScreenRights.Any(y => y.ScreenId == screenId))
                                .Skip(page * pageSize)
                                .Take(pageSize)
                                .ToList();

            foreach (var right in rights)
            {
                // Remove the screen from any rights that used it
                right.ScreenRights.RemoveAll(x => x.ScreenId == screenId);

                // You might want to delete any empty rights declarations
                if (right.ScreenRights.Count == 0)
                    session.Delete(right);
            }

            // Exit when we get back less than a full page, indicating there are no more pages.
            if (rights.Count < pageSize)
                break;

            // Next page please.
            page++;
        }

        // Delete the screen.
        session.Delete(screen);

        // Save all your changes together.
        session.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to use Raven's [Patching API](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates) to perform the update.  It's faster, but you don't have transactional guarantees.

You can also look at Raven's [Cascading Deletes Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/cascade-delete), but I don't think it would work here because you're not necessarily deleting the `RightsDeclaration` every time.

**Update**

I pushed out some of the harder paging code into an easy-to-consume extension method.  This is now part of the [ravendb/contrib](https://github.com/ravendb/contrib) project.  Using those extensions, your code is much simpler:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var screen = session.Load<Screen>(screenId);
    if (screen != null)
    {
        // Get all rights that use this screen.
        session.Query<RightsDeclaration>()
                .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
                .Where(x => x.ScreenRights.Any(y => y.ScreenId == screenId))
                .ForEachWithPaging(right =>
                    {
                        // Remove the screen from any rights that used it
                        right.ScreenRights.RemoveAll(x => x.ScreenId == screenId);

                        // You might want to delete any empty rights declarations
                        if (right.ScreenRights.Count == 0)
                            session.Delete(right);
                    });

        // Delete the screen.
        session.Delete(screen);

        // Save all your changes together.
        session.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! Matt that was a great solution.It works perfect.+100 for you. And I need one more help Please give me brief explanation on the query or refer some documentation explaining what you have done in the query. sorry to be so silly I don't know why page,page size and now are all used here that's why i asked it.

Comment: Raven limits the number of query results returned, as part of the "Safe by Default" philosophy.  If you don't specify a .Take(), it cuts you off at 128 results.  If you do specify one, you can't go higher than the `Raven/MaxPageSize` setting, which is 1024 unless you change it.  Review http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/paging  and  http://ravendb.net/docs/intro/safe-by-default

Comment: Also - If you have a large amount of `RightsDeclaration` classes (> 1024 * 30), it's possible you might run into a limit with the number of requests that can be made in a single session.  The extension method I referenced in the update takes that into account and adjusts appropriately.